# Extract text containing match between new line characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to extract paragraphs from OCR'd contracts if that paragraph contains key search terms using JS. A user might search for something such as "ship ahead" to find clauses relating to whether a certain customers orders can be shipped early.

I've been banging my head up against a regex wall for quite some time and am clearly just not grasping something.

If I have text like this and I'm searching for the word "match":

```
let text = "\n\nThis is an example of a paragraph that has the word I'm looking for The word is Match. \n\nThis paragraph does not have the word I want."
```

I would want to extract all the text between the double \n characters and not return the second sentence in that string.

I've been trying some form of:

```
let string = `[^\n\n]*match[^.]*\n\n`;

let re = new RegExp(string, "gi");
let body = text.match(re);
```

However that returns null. Oddly if I remove the periods from the string it works (sorta):

```
[
  "This is an example of a paragraph that has the word I'm looking for The word is Match \n" +
    '\n'
]
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Try this: `[^\n].*match.*[^\n]`. edit: this I guess? Maybe? `\n{2,}(.*match.*)\n{2,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting some text between identical delimiters containing some specific text is not quite possible without any hacks related to context matching.

Thus, you may simply split the text into paragraphs and get those containing your match:

```js
const results = text.split(/\n{2,}/).filter(x=>/\bmatch\b/i.test(x))
```

You may remove word boundaries if you do not need a whole word match.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let text = "\n\nThis is an example of a paragraph that has the word I'm looking for The word is Match. \n\nThis paragraph does not have the word I want.";
console.log(text.split(/\n{2,}/).filter(x=>/\bmatch\b/i.test(x)));
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!! What if I want to make the search term dynamic? Template literal's don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty easy if you use the fact that a `.` matches all characters except newline by default. Use regex `/.*match.*/` with a greedy `.*` on both sides:

```js
const text = 'aaaa\n\nbbb match ccc\n\nddd';
const regex = /.*match.*/;
console.log(text.match(regex).toString());
```

Output:

```
bbb match ccc
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is two ways to do it. I am not sure why u need to use regular expression. Split seems much easier to do, isn't it?

```js
const text = "\n\nThis is an example of a paragraph that has the word I'm looking for The word is Match. \n\nThis paragraph does not have the word I want."

// regular expression one

function getTextBetweenLinesUsingRegex(text) {
  const regex = /\n\n([^(\n\n)]+)\n\n/;
  const arr = regex.exec(text);
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    return arr[1];
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(`getTextBetweenLinesUsingRegex: ${ getTextBetweenLinesUsingRegex(text)}`);

console.log(`simple: ${text.split('\n\n')[1]}`);
```